# How to add a script.ps1 in C# proiect

Tags: c#, powershell, dll, process, resources

I added the script3.ps1 file in my project resources.
I build the dll file.

I want to start a powershell process with script.ps1.
I tried

```
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "powershell.exe",
        Arguments = "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command \".'"+MyProject.Properties.Resources.script3+"'",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
```

I received the error:

```
the term 'system.byte[]' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file or operable program. check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that path is correct and try again. at line : 1 char
```

Answer (score 3):

Save resource contentsto file first:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("file3.ps", MyProject.Properties.Resources.script3);
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "powershell.exe",
        Arguments = "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command \".\\file3.ps\"",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
```

Or if its one-liner just convert to string:

```
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "powershell.exe",
        Arguments = "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command \""+Encoding.Default.GetString(MyProject.Properties.Resources.script3)+"\"",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
```

Comment: The first sample working fine but I don't want to create a file on disk. I have a script with multiple line so I can't use the second sample.